# Baffled by join results after adding WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of clients associated with each health clinic, and I want to show all clinics even if the number of clients is 0. My query works as expected until I throw in a WHERE clause.

Here's a stripped down description of the database tables and query to get to the essence of the problem.

### clients table

```
client_id | health_clinic_id | accepted  
----------------------------------------
1           1                  1  
2           2                  NULL  
3           1                  1
```

### options_health_clinics table

```
health_clinic_id | health_clinic_name  
--------------------------------------
1                  South Valley  
2                  North Valley  
3                  East Valley  
4                  West Valley
```

The following query does what I expect, i.e because of the RIGHT JOIN all health clinics are shown even if the number of clients is 0 for a health clinic.

```
SELECT  
    options_health_clinics.health_clinic_name,  
    COALESCE(COUNT(clients.health_clinic_id), 0) AS n_clients

FROM clients
    RIGHT JOIN options_health_clinics ON options_health_clinics.health_clinic_id = clients.health_clinic_id

GROUP BY options_health_clinics.health_clinic_id
```

As soon as I throw in the WHERE clause (below) to filter out clients who have not accepted, only the health clinics with non-zero counts are shown.

```
WHERE clients.accepted = 1
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: Boy, I can't believe how LEFT-JOINed I am.  It's tough understanding this as a RIGHT JOIN :)

Comment: Here you go for left joined people:

FROM options_health_clinics 
    LEFT JOIN clients ON options_health_clinics.health_clinic_id = clients.health_clinic_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to move the WHERE condition to the ON condition.

```
RIGHT JOIN options_health_clinics
  ON options_health_clinics.health_clinic_id = clients.health_clinic_id
    AND clients.accepted = 1
```

This will include only clients where accepted is 1 before the clients are joined to the options_health_clinics.

Comment: Yes, that works putting the AND condition with the ON clause. I never knew you could do that. I thought joins were simply joining another table with an ON condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you need non-null client acceptance then you can try this-

```
SELECT  
    options_health_clinics.health_clinic_name,  
    COALESCE(COUNT(clients.health_clinic_id), 0) AS n_clients

FROM clients
    RIGHT JOIN options_health_clinics ON options_health_clinics.health_clinic_id = clients.health_clinic_id

WHERE clients.accepted IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY options_health_clinics.health_clinic_id
```

Comment: I just tried using the IS NOT NULL, and it also does not show all health clinics. Basically, I think it's the same problem. The comments below

Answer (score 0):

When there are no clients, then clients.accepted is NULL. Try:

```
WHERE clients.accepted = 1 OR clients.accepted IS NULL
```

Comment: Your suggestion does return all the health clinics, however the logic doesn't work for this situation because I don't want the client to be counted if clients.accepted IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It breaks because you are right joining clients to options_health_clinics which returns all the options_health_clinics rows but not all the clients.  By adding the where clause clients.accepted = 1 you filter out all the clinics without clients because clients.accepted is null for all those rows and <> 1

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your explanation. Do you have a different suggestion than the one that suggests moving the AND condition to the ON clause?